# problems with rebinding function when cloning an object

Tags: javascript, bind

I have an object with properties of type object and one of these contains functions, that are bound to the "base" object.
When i now try to clone that "base" object, i clone also every property of type object to ensure that there are no references to old data left and i also try to bind the mentioned functions to the new cloned object (because they use a this reference), but when i change some values in the clone and use one of these functions they seem to be still bound to the old "base" object.

Anyone got an idea why this is happening?

Comment: Do any of the functions have closures over the old data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's about attempts to "rebind" functions that are bound by `Function.prototype.bind()` call then you are out of luck.

The `bind()` creates **new** function-wrapper - closure around original function and its `this`. As with any other "closured" variables - you simply have no access to them and so cannot change them from outside. And so you cannot "rebind" bound function.

Check: [Can you rebind a rebound function using `bind`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43637765/can-you-rebind-a-rebound-function-using-bind)