# `onStartedProcess` callback never get called

Tags: javascript, node.js

I bind a function with this code

```
this.process[id].on('started', this.onStartedProcess.bind(this)); // I    want to pass an extra variable here.
```

Then, in the process, when I call this code

```
that.emit('started', {startTime:time, instance: that});
```

The following function is called

```
onStartedProcess(info) {
console.log(info.startTime);
}
```

Is it possible to pass an extra variable to the `onStartedProcess` function when biding it? Something like

```
this.process[id].on('started', this.onStartedProcess.bind(this,otherParameter));
```

and use the parameter when the `onStartedProcess` is called because of the emit, for example

```
onStartedProcess(info, otherParameter) {
console.log(info.startTime);
console.log(otherParameter);
}
```

I red this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/use-of-the-javascript-bind-method) about the bind method but still can't find a way to achieve what I want to do.

**Edit:** 
This is not working for me. This is what I tried

```
this.process[id].on('started', this.onStartedProcess.bind(this, 5));

that.emit('started', {startTime:time, instance: that});

    onStartedProcess(info, otherParameter) {
    console.log(otherParameter); // I was expecting the get the 5 here
    }
```

`onStartedProcess` never get called

Comment: yes this is how `bind` work, first parameter is the `this` value inside the 'binded' function, other parameters are the function parameters in the order of their declaration. You may give only one, two or all parameters.

Comment: Yes that should work. Read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20925268/3008050) for detailed understanding.

Comment: This is not working for me

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You are describing how `bind` function works. First pass the context (`this`), then all additional parameters you need.
Read the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

---

The problem is with the arguments order in the function you are binding.

```
onStartedProcess(info, otherParameter) {
    // with your current `.onStartedProcess.bind(this, 5)
    // you are binding `info` argument to `5`
    console.log(otherParameter); // I was expecting the get the 5 here
}
```

If you want to currently set `otherParameter` to `5` you need to properly bind the second argument: `.bind(thisArg, firstArg, SecondArg)`

---

Regarding to the callback not being called.
This is one solution for your scenario:

// `parent.js`

```
const { fork } = require('child_process');
const subprocess = fork('child.js');

subprocess.send('start');
subprocess.send({ hello: 'world' });
```

// `child.js`

```
process.on('message', onStartedProcess.bind(null, 'first arg', 5));

function onStartedProcess(info, otherParameter, message) {
    console.info('callback args:', info, otherParameter, message);
}
```

Running `node parent.js` you should get this output:

> callback args: first arg 5 start
>
> callback args: first arg 5 { hello: 'world' }

---

Read more about node process messaging [here](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_send_message_sendhandle_options_callback)

Comment: This is  not working for me, I updated my question

Comment: I just update my answer taking into account your new info provided. The problem is with the `bind` arguments order. Try this:  `this.onStartedProcess.bind(this, 'info-binded-value', 5)`

Comment: Thank you but even so onStartedProcess still not getting called

Comment: That's a different problem than `passing extra argument when binding function` in javascript