# JS What does bind() do to prevent my code from being re-bound to another this context?

Tags: javascript, binding

I'm learning about the hard binding in JS and experimenting with it. So I made my custom bind utility function and I'm using it upon the result given from the official JavaScript bind method.

```js
function foo(a, b) {
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;

  console.log(this.a);
  console.log(this.b);
}

function customBind(fn, obj) {
  return function(args) {
    fn.apply(obj, args);
  }
}

var obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
}

var obj2 = {
  a: 2,
  b: 3
}

var myFunc = foo.bind(obj, 200, 300);
var myNewFunc = customBind(myFunc, obj2);
myNewFunc([400, 500]);
```

The result of this in the console is:

```
200
300
```

So what happens in this code? Can you explain the algorithm that the bind method uses to prevent this reassignment to me?

Comment: change foo to `function foo(a, b, ...c)` - then add `console.log(this, c)` in `foo` - then you should see what is happening

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

If I were to code the bind functionality myself, it would look something like this:

```
Function.prototype.bind = function(thisArg, ...args) {

  // bind is a function on the Function's prototype, therefore it will be
  // in the 'this' variable of this function. For further reference see link 1. below.
  var originalFunc = this;

  // A new function is returned wrapping the original function. When this new function is
  // called it will call the original function with the thisArg and other args passed
  // to the bind function and appends the args passed to this new function after
  // the arguments passed to `bind`.
  return function(...secondaryArgs) {
     return originalFunc.call(thisArg, ...args, ...secondaryArgs);
  }
}
```

<sup>*Note: This isn't entirely according to the spec, but it should give you an overal idea on how this would work.*</sup>

As you can see calling the function returned by `bind` with another set of arguments (which is what you are supposedly are trying to do) does not replace the arguments passed to `bind`, but instead appends them at the very end.

This is why your example does not work as expected:

```
function foo(a, b) {
    console.log(a, b);
}

var newFunc = foo.bind({}, 200, 300);
foo(400, 500); // prints: 200, 300 instead of what you expected: 400, 500
```

Changing your example a bit to understand what is going on:

```
function bar(a, b, c, d) {
    console.log(a, b, c, d);
}

var newFunc = bar.bind({}, 200, 300);
newFunc(400, 500); // prints: 200, 300, 400, 500
```

Note the 400, 500 are appended after the 200, 300.

The following would also work:

```
var newFunc = foo.bind({});
foo(400, 500); // prints: 400, 500
```

---

Links

1. [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Edit:

- Apparently `bind` appends the arguments instead of ignoring them.

Comment: What about the new object (obj2)? Why doesn't the new object get passed as well? I think apply and call have some algorithm that checks whether the function is hard bound and if it's hard bound it ignores the new object. Is that the case?

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question at first.

This may answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20925138/bind-more-arguments-of-an-already-bound-function-in-javascript#answer-20925268