# vuejs - .bind(this) not working as expected

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/23959y5wnp

So I'm passing down a function and would like to rebind the `this` so I used `.bind(this)` on the function, yet the data returned is still based on the original component. What am I missing?

*Expected:* `Test2` should print out `Test2` on button click

**Code:**

*App.vue*

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img width="25%" src="./assets/logo.png" /><br />
    <Test1 :aFunction="passThis" /> <Test2 :aFunction="dontPassThis" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Test1 from "./components/Test1";
import Test2 from "./components/Test2";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Test1,
    Test2
  },
  data() {
    return {
      value: "original"
    };
  },
  methods: {
    dontPassThis($_) {
      console.log(this.value);
    },
    passThis($_) {
      console.log($_.value);
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

*Test1.vue*

```
<template>
  <div>Test1 <button @click="() => aFunction(this)">click me</button></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      value: "Test1"
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.aFunction(this);
  },
  props: {
    aFunction: {
      required: true,
      type: Function
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

*Test2.vue*

```
<template>
  <div>
    Test2

    <button @click="testFunction">click me</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      testFunction: null,
      value: "Test2"
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.testFunction = this.aFunction.bind(this);
  },
  props: {
    aFunction: {
      required: true,
      type: Function
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: `testFunction` is not a property of the exported object. `testFunction` is an object returned from the `data` function within the exported object..

Comment: @guest271314 for `Test2.vue` I've also tried changing the `@click` to `() => aFunction.bind(this)()`. But it still prints out "original"

Comment: Have not tried vue.js. Where is the `data` function called?

Comment: @guest271314 that data function just sets up the component so that the variables inside the returned object are accessible via the `this.X`

Comment: Why are there two different exported objects that have a property with the same name `"data"`?

Comment: @guest271314 what do you mean there are two different exported objects? They're different components.

Comment: As previously mentioned, have not tried vue.js. Where is `data() {
    return {
      testFunction: null,
      value: "Test2"
    };
  }` executed in the code at the question?

Comment: @guest271314 well I don't really think you can help me then. Just too much to explain on the fundamentals. Thanks for trying though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vue already [binds the component's methods](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/33e669b/src/core/instance/state.js#L286) during initialization, and  [functions cannot be bound more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20925268/6277151) (subsequent binds have no effect).

So when `App` is initialized, Vue binds the `App` instance as the context of its `dontPassThis` method. `App` "passes" `dontPassThis` to `Test2` via a prop, which `Test2` subsequently tries to bind, which actually does nothing.