# JavaScript: Reset function binding

Tags: javascript, function, object, binding, this

For some reasons I got to bind a function, say like this:

```js
function test() {
  console.log(this);
}

test();               // Window
test = test.bind({});
test();               // Object {  }
```

No I could add the line

```js
test = test.bind(null);
```

to bind to another object. But `test` will still return `{}` instead of `null`, it seems to be *bound to `{}` forever*.

But is it really? I could of course store the initial definition of `test` inside a variable `initialTest`, say, before binding, and to reset simply do

```
test = initialTest;
```

But can it be done more easily?

---

It would in fact do to instead of `test = test.bind(context);` call

```
function bindTest(context) {
  test = (function () {
    console.log(this);
  }).bind(context);
}
```

every time the context of `test` shall be changed and therefore remove the initial global definition of `test` (which is the same as calling

```
bindTest(window);
```

at the beginning).

But maybe there is a more elegant way to do it...

Comment: [You can only `bind` a function once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20925138/bind-more-arguments-of-an-already-bound-function-in-javascript). What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: It would do to override `test` by a function with the same body but bound to another object

Comment: Then you should do `const test1 = test.bind(something); const test2 = test.bind(somethingElse);`. I.e. do not overwrite `test`.

Comment: And I wanna do this without storing the old function before binding

Comment: But in my context it is necessary to keep the name `test` (rather not elaborate on my rather intricate context)

Comment: But let's assume the same call `test()` shall always call the same function but with changing context

Comment: How about naming the initial function differently and only ever assign the bound functions to `test`?

Comment: I added something like that to my question, but still I'm not quite satisfied